# How can I ensure kubernetes pods (sitting behind nginx) can complete in-flight requests before pods are terminated?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, lifecycle, kubernetes-pod

My infrastructure has pods running on k8s with nginx sitting in the middle. According to the k8s pod lifecycle documentation, if you remove a pod, 1 second later it's removed from the endpoints list so no new requests are sent to it and nginx can no longer resolve it.

Am I correct in understanding that as soon as the pod is removed from the endpoints list that it's basically non-existent despite the fact that it's likely still alive and processing the SIGTERM request?

If yes, is there a way to give it a chance to complete in-flight requests while not accepting new ones?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, as soon as pod is marked as `Terminating` it cannot (normally) receive traffic. If you want to ensure connections are drained, you use the `preStop` hook described here:

(https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination).

We use this to drain connections from our Varnish deployment before it terminates, because in our setup, they don't drain "naturally" fast enough, and connections are abruptly terminated when the pods get the SIGKILL signal.

Comment: Yes, I understand that they can't receive traffic, but what I am unclear of is whether the pods can still complete existing in flight requests after being from removed from the list of nginx endpoints. The documentation is not clear to me on this point.

Comment: The documentation does not mention it because it is up to the code itself to handle the signal appropriately. Code that runs within the pod should (if possible) detect and handle the SIGTERM signal and try to clean up itself before it gets forcibly killed. To answer your question, the pod _can_ and _should_ clean up inflight requests before terminating if possible. If it can't do so in time, then you should use the `preStop` hook to assist in that.

Comment: From the page shared above - Note: When a Pod is being deleted, it is shown as Terminating by some kubectl commands. This Terminating status is not one of the Pod phases. A Pod is granted a term to terminate gracefully, which defaults to 30 seconds.