# Kubernetes Conditional Updates/Rollout

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes Deployment that runs tasks which are triggered by the user. These tasks run for different periods of time (1sec to 10min). These tasks cannot be interrupted as it messes with the task progress/outcome and status within the DB. When deploying a new version of code, I want to ensure that the update (kubectl apply ...) doesn't terminate the old pod until there are no more jobs running on it. New jobs can be routed to the new Deployment.

So the question is can I setup a conditional statement within Kubernetes to ensure a Deployment is not terminated until its not processing a task? (I have an restful endpoint setup to return true or false if there are any tasks running)

I've read the Kubernetes docs and I wasn't able to find a way to conditionally rollout Deployments

Comment: "as it messes with the outcome and status within the DB" - this is what transactions are for.

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question?  There is a dedicated exchange for devops questions. https://devops.stackexchange.com/ To be clear, kubernetes questions have the requirement "KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT. Configuration and deployment is off-topic here. "    Emphasis not mine

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74829655/in-kubernetes-is-there-a-way-to-make-statefulset-pods-linger-to-finish-requests/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70963097/how-can-i-ensure-kubernetes-pods-sitting-behind-nginx-can-complete-in-flight-r/